# can websites record screen/take screenshots?

Tags: html, web, screen, screenshot, recording

I wanted to know if it's possible for a website to record the screen or take screenshots of the screen or of the webpage itself (for example to monitor what the user is looking at on the website)

thanks

Comment: a website page with Javascript enabled can, if the user permits, capture that screen & page - but you already know what the user is looking at without needing to do that. Perhaps [Mozilla would be useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, websites can understand which key on keyboard you type, so if you  hit on printscreen button on windows, active open website can understand you take a screenshot. No, not really. Some apps like Snapchat will tell the other user about a screen shot.